# Lychrel number Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, lychrel-numbers

Recently became fascinated with the search for Lychrel and palindromic numbers as recreational mathematics.

for the who are unaware, the process for performing this check on a number manually is as follows.

1. Let x be some number.
2. Let R(x) be the number corresponding to x written in reverse.
3. Let n = x + R(x)
4. If n == R(n), then return `True`, else `False`.

Repeat with `n` as the new `x` until `True` is obtained.

is there any way to automate this in Python? where I can enter a number and it will tell me if the sum of its reverse is a palindrome. Additionally, I'd like to see how many steps it would take to reach the number.

Example:

Let x be 79. 79 + 97 is 176, which is not a palindrome, so we get `False`.

Let x now be 176. 176 + 671 is 847, which is not a palindrome, so we get `False`.

We continue:

- 847 + 748 == 1595
- 1595 + 5951 == 7546
- 7546 + 6457 == 14003
- 14003 + 30041 = 44044

This is where we finally hit a palindrome. It took 6 steps.

Comment: Jacob, if you want to do this in Python, then this is indeed not the right forum. This is specifically for users of the Wolfram *Mathematica* software system.

Comment: Please properly format your question.

Comment: I don't know if this is a good fit for StackOverflow either. This site is about _getting stuck while writing software_, not pondering how one might write software and then asking a group of random developers how they might do it. You're supposed to have started/have an idea what you're doing.

Comment: I don't have any experience programming but I thought this might be an interesting project to get my feet wet. I'm just trying to gather information on the best way to proceed with my concept.

Comment: I discussed Lychrel numbers at <a href="http://programmingpraxis.com/2015/09/01/lychrel-numbers/">my blog</a> today. Among the solutions there is some Python code.

Comment: @user448810 I think the syntax you're looking for is `[my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2015/09/01/lychrel-numbers/)`, which becomes: [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2015/09/01/lychrel-numbers/)

Comment: I tried to make your question more readable and better formatted. Hope I haven't screwed it up!

Comment: Note that `1595 + 5951 == 7546` - `79` has six steps to `44044`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I edited the post with the corrected math. thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I discussed Lychrel numbers at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2015/09/01/lychrel-numbers/) today. Among the solutions there is some Python code. Thanks, @jonrsharpe, for the syntax correction.

Answer (score 3):

First, define two convenience functions (you can do this yourself!):

```
def is_palindrome(number):
    """Whether the number is a palindrome."""
    raise NotImplementedError

def reverse(number):
    """The number reversed, e.g. 79 -> 97."""
    raise NotImplementedError
```

Then we can create a [*generator*](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) that produces the series of numbers you describe:

```
def process(number):
    """Create the required series of numbers."""
    while True:
        yield number
        if is_palindrome(number):
            break
        number += reverse(number)
```

For example:

```
>>> list(process(79))
[79, 176, 847, 1595, 7546, 14003, 44044]
# 0    1    2     3     4      5      6
```

---

Determining whether a number is a Lychrel number is trickier - obviously it's trivial to say when it *isn't*, as our generator runs out:

```
def is_lychrel(number):
    """Whether the number is a Lychrel number."""
    for _ in process(number):
        pass
    return False
```

And you could test whether we repeat a number (if there's a loop, it cannot ever reach a palindrome):

```
def is_lychrel(number):
    """Whether the number is a Lychrel number."""
    seen = set()
    for num in process(number):
        if num in seen:
            return True
        seen.update((num, reverse(num)))  # thanks @ReblochonMasque
    return False
```

But otherwise it will continue until you run out of memory!

Comment: I downloaded python 3.5 x64 and Notepad++. which would be best for writing and running this script? I'm sorry, I have basically no experience with this.

Comment: @JacobK perhaps you should find and follow an introductory tutorial? The script is just text, so it doesn't really matter whether you edit it in IDLE, Notepad++ or something else.

Comment: @johnsharpe you can add both the numbers and the reversed ones in the set.

Comment: @johnsharpe, you can also add each number (and their reverse) found  in the sequences yielded by process()

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I didn't quite follow that, sorry

Comment: any number contained in a non lychrel number sequence will be non lychrel itself - and so is its reverse. (you may want to cap the size though, because as the depth of iteration increases, the numbers are very sparse and the importance of memoizing them becomes trivial)

Comment: @ReblochonMasque ah, I see, you're talking about having a cache of non-Lychrel numbers outside `is_lychrel`?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean, plus feeding every tested number (the ones returned by process()) into it.

Answer (score 2):

A little experiment about the chains length distribution in Mathematica:

```
f[n_] := NestWhileList[# + FromDigits@k &, n,
                       (# != (k = Reverse@#)) &@IntegerDigits[#] & ] // Length

(* remove known lychrel candidates *)
list = f /@  Complement[Range@1000, {196, 295, 394, 493, 592, 689, 691, 788, 790, 879, 
                                     887, 978, 986}];

Histogram@list
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The same till 3700:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

First we have a function that reverses the digits of a number:

```
def rev(n, r=0):
    if n == 0: return r
    return rev(n // 10, r*10 + n%10)
```

Then we can use that to determine whether or not a number is a Lychrel number; here we return the chain that disproves the Lychrel-ness of the number, or a singleton list to indicate that the number is Lychrel:

```
def lychrel(n, bound=1000):
    r = rev(n); chain = [n]
    while bound > 0:
        n += r; r = rev(n)
        chain.append(n)
        if n == r: return chain
        bound -= 1
    return [chain[0]]
```

Here are some examples:

```
>>> lychrel(196)
[196]
>>> lychrel(281)
[281, 463, 827, 1555, 7106, 13123, 45254]
```

You can read more about Lychrel numbers at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2015/09/01/lychrel-numbers/).

**EDIT:** After being challenged by Tony Suffolk 66, I did the timing tests that I proposed to him. You can see them at http://ideone.com/5gTbSH. My recursive function that uses only integers is about 30% faster than his function that converts to a string and back. Faster still is an iterative version of the function that uses only integers.

I'm normally a Scheme programmer, not a Python programmer, and I was surprised at the difference between the iterative and recursive versions, which I attribute to Python's function-calling overhead. When I do the same experiment in Scheme, there is essentially no difference between the iterative and recursive versions, which makes sense because the recursion is in tail position and is thus essentially iterative.

Comment: @user44810 using `int("".join(reversed(str(n))))` has got to be far more efficient than using your recursive function. Your function is clever, but clever isn't always best.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66: I think you are wrong. Please produce timing tests to show that your function, which converts from integer to string, creates a generator to produce the characters of the string in reverse order,collects the generated characters into a string, and converts back to an integer is faster than my function that operates solely on integers.

Comment: it would be an interesting test - when I have the time. will have a play.

Answer (score 1):

My code is less Pythonic than jonrsharpe, but closer to your example.  First define a file I called palindrome.py:

```
def reverseInt(x):
    """Return the digit-reversed version of integer x (digits in decimal)."""
    #Convert to string, because strings are iterable.  Obtain a reverse
    #  iterator to the characters.
    Rx = reversed(str(x))
    #Obtain reversed string by joining with no intervening characters
    Rx = "".join(Rx)
    #Switch back to integer
    Rx = int(Rx)
    return Rx

def iteration(x):
    """Return a 2-tuple (n, done) where n is the result of one iteration of
    the palindrome search, and done is a boolean flag indicating whether n is
    a palindrome."""
    Rx = reverseInt(x)
    n = x + Rx
    Rn = reverseInt(n)
    return n, n==Rn

def depth(x):
    """Return a 2-tuple (y, numIter) where y is a palindrome and numIter
    is the number of palindrome iterations needed to obtain y from x."""
    numIter = 0
    if x == reverseInt(x):
        return x, numIter
    done = False
    while not done:
        x, done = iteration(x)
        numIter += 1
    return x, numIter
```

Now run python

```
python
>>> import palindrome as pD
>>> #pD is only for brevity, I'm being a lazy typist
>>> pD.iteration(79)
(176, False)
>>> pD.depth(79)
(44044, 6)
```

Comment: Easier for a beginner of Python to understand.  Also, jonrsharpe hasn't yet provided a meaningful body for the is_palindrome and reverse functions.

Comment: The `is_palindrome` and `reverse` for ints are duplicates and have been answered before here, but they're both extremely easy in Python. `reverse_int = lambda n: int(str(n)[::-1])` which makes `is_palindromic_int = lambda n: int(n) == reverse_int(n)` or something. You don't have to use lambdas it's just easier to read in comments.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: They aren't so hard, but after the original poster said he had no programming experience, I figured a complete solution which was also implemented in a very simple manner, with comments, would be best.  I didn't know about slices including a step (of -1, in this case).  Thanks.

Comment: @jacobK: it would be considerate to select one of the answers as the "answer" to your question.